# Controller virtual path is built incorrectly when application deployed in Azure environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a working application in MVC.net which I am trying to migrate Azure environment.

Code to create virtual path to access controller is:

```
var populateEmailsUrl = '<%= Url.Action("PopulateEmailNotifications","ABC") %>';
```

where `ABC` is the controller name and `PopulateEmailNotifications` is the method name.

When accessed from any environment or localhost Azure it is rendered correctly as:

```
var populateEmailsUrl = '/appgroup/0021a/web/ABC/PopulateEmailNotifications/';
```

When accessed from azure public URL it is rendered as:

```
var populateEmailsUrl = '/appgroup/0021a/web/XYZ/PopulateEmailNotifications/';
```

`XYZ` is another controller in application

This is not true with all the controllers. Some of them are rendered correctly.

Comment: You'll need to show us your routing table and how your controllers are organised

Comment: @teresko If by routing table you mean entries in global.asax file then there was no entry related to "ABC" controller in that file. So tried by inserting it but it did not work. The path for controllers are Source\PQR\ProjectName\Controllers\ABC\ABCcontroller.cs and Source\PQR\ProjectName\Controllers\XYZ\XYZController.cs.

Comment: @trailmax refer above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved my application from MVC 2 to MVC 3 and it solved my problem.